# Flight to Baghdad from Heathrow

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airports, transit, layovers

I posted a question earlier about a problem I had when I travelled to Jordan few months ago.

I had a flight to Jordan from Gatwick to stay few days in Jordan, so at the time my final destination was Jordan.
My departure was fine from Gatwick, however when I reached Jordan there were some slight problems that affected my entrance. The problem was is that I used to live in Jordan for 2 years and I left it 2004, when I left it at the borders they told us we wouldn't be allowed to enter Jordan for another 4 years (it's a rule they used to have for people who stay in Jordan and then leave it).
When I had my flight few months ago to Jordan at the passport control in Amman airport the issue about the 4 years rule popped up and they seemed to have misspelled my mother's name when I left Jordan in 2004. It took them some time to allow us to enter Jordan. I don't know if the issue still exists.

I've got a flight from Heathrow to Baghdad with Royal Jordanian in few days, this flight has a layover of 10 hours in Jordan. I was just wondering at Heathrow when I check in with the airline do they care if I have any issues in entering Jordan that could affect my boarding? Or do they not look for such issues with passengers? Can they actually see on their computers if I had any issues with a country I'm travelling to when they scan my passport? Same question goes for the passport control at the gates in the airport.

I was thinking I wouldn't have any issues at Heathrow because my final destination is Baghdad anyway and not Jordan, but just wanted to ask you to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The airline check-in counter is not going to bother with the Jordanian leg of the flight since <strike>you'll fall under Transit Without Visa (TWOV) for that part</strike> SEE EDIT. What they *will* check though is your visa for Iraq, and if needed, they'll seek pre-authorisation from UK Border Agency and note down your visa details. Also, since the airline has no access to Jordanian passport control's database, they'll simply consider you as any other passenger transiting in Jordan.

**Edit:** [According to Timaticweb, you do need a visa for Iraq](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=GB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IQ&TR=JO&user=DL&subuser=DELTAB2C). Furthermore, Jordan's TWOV rules only allow for a maximum transit time of six hours, and in case of transit times between six to 24 hours, you need to leave your passport at the passport control desk. Since you're only transiting, this may or may not be a problem in case their system flags you as a person who's not allowed into Jordan.

> Jordan
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 6 hours.
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting for longer than 6 hours, but less than 24
>   hours must leave the airport. Passports must be left at the
>   immigration desk. The airlines can arrange this.

I would suggest calling up the [Jordanian Embassy in UK](http://www.jordanembassy.org.uk/).

Comment: I have a British Passport so I don't think I need a visa to Iraq

Comment: Apparently, you do. See updated answer.

Comment: The thing is I travelled to Iraq a year ago and got a visa from the Embassy here, but when I arrived at the Iraqi airport they told me you didn't need the visa. As for the 6 hours max rule the airline arranged for us to go to a hotel to wait, which is outside the airport. I hope they let us in, otherwise we might need to wait in the airport

Comment: Also on the Timaticweb site you gave, in the destination section it says this: Visa required, except for Holders of British passports

Comment: Also this: Former nationals of Iraq, provided passport clearly states

  place of birth to be in Iraq or if holding an ID Card issued
  by Iraq can obtain a visa on arrival at Baghdad (BGW) or
  Basra (BSR). 

My passport clearly says I was born in Iraq

Comment: I see. You didn't add those details about being a former national of Iraq. Also, the "except for British passport holders" continues saying for "endorsed British citizens" which I'm assuming is done by the embassy. Anyway, hope you don't run into trouble in Jordan!

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to ask you, do they check if I have a visa at Heathrow or when I arrive at Baghdad? Because my flight is in two days and I haven't got a visa. If they only check it at Baghdad I could get on-arrival one from there, but I'm worried that they might check if I have one at Heathrow.

Comment: @ManFire Your airline will do a preliminary check at Heathrow to determine whether you'll be allowed to enter the country, because if you're denied entry they'll have to fly you back. And when you go through passport control in Baghdad the authorities there will of course do the actual check.

Comment: So do you mean at Heathrow when the airline checks me in will they ask me if I have a visa or not? Will they allow me to board if I tell them I'm a former Iraqi national but I don't have a visa?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4473/discussion-between-ankur-banerjee-and-man-fire)